# Сортировка коллекции элементов по возрастанию

Tags: javascript

Насколько я понял, читая документацию по JS, "массив" DOV-элементов, вытянутых JS'ом, например, по определенным атрибутам называется "коллекцией". Самое интересное для меня то, что `console.log()` отображает их в виде массива (квадратные скобки), но `typeof()` явно говорит, что это объект. Соответственно, если коллекция - это объект, то методы, доступные обычному массиву, коллекции недоступны.

Теперь ближе к делу. Есть у меня HTML примерно такого содержания:

```
<a data-sort="3">link</a>
<section data-sort="4">section</section>
<div data-sort="2">block</div>
<a>just a link, without data-sort</a>
<span data-sort="1">line</span>
```

JavaScript вытягивает все элементы на странице, у которых есть атрибут `data-sort`:

```
collection = document.querySelectorAll("[data-sort]");
```

Сейчас элементы записаны в том порядке, в котором они есть на странице (3, 4, 2, 1). Но мне нужно, чтобы в коллекции они хранились в порядке, указанном в самом атрибуте `data-sort`.

Я решил использовать функцию `sort()`. Но эта функция доступна только для массивов. Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
collection.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: collection.sort is not a function

Это понятно, ведь мы пытаемся сортировать узлы (nodes), а узлы не больше и не меньше друг друга. Надо сортировать по атрибуту (в котором и записан нужный порядок). Давайте получим массив из атрибутов:

```
dataAttrs = [];
collection.forEach(function(item, i, coll) {
  dataAttrs[i] = item.getAttribute("data-sort");
});
```

Теперь мы имеем массив вида 3, 4, 2, 1. Его уже можно отсортировать:

```
dataAttrs.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
```

Готово. Итого мое решение заняло довольно много места и в конце-концов мы имеем отсортированный массив атрибутов и несортированную коллекцию элементов.

**Вопрос:** как улучшить этот код и все-таки отсортировать не массив атрибутов по значениям (по возрастанию), а саму коллекцию, основываясь на ее атрибутах?

Comment: попробуй сделать `typeof []` :)

Comment: @Grundy не совсем понял где сделать и при чем тут это.

Comment: @Grundy а, вы, видимо, хотели сказать, что `typeof([])` тоже даст object? Ну тогда я вам скажу, что не буду удивлен, ведь `typeof(null)` тоже даст object! Пусть это и баг.

Comment: в случае с массивов это не баг, да и с нулом тоже не особо баг

Comment: @Grundy в случае с null, как раз-таки, __официально признанный__ баг, если верить learn.javascript.ru и подобным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коллекция же не имеет метода сортировки, поэтому тупо копирую элементы в новый массив и сортирую в примере ниже:

```js
collection = document.querySelectorAll("[data-sort]");
var newColl = []

for (var i = collection.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  newColl.push(collection[i]);
}

newColl.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.getAttribute("data-sort") - b.getAttribute("data-sort");
});
console.log(newColl);
```

```html
<a data-sort="3">link</a>
<section data-sort="4">section</section>
<div data-sort="2">block</div>
<a>just a link, without data-sort</a>
<span data-sort="1">line</span>
```

Грунди обычно ваяет что-то наподобие этого, заимствует методы и прочую пургу))

```js
collection = document.querySelectorAll("[data-sort]");

var arr = [].slice.call(collection);
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.getAttribute("data-sort") - b.getAttribute("data-sort");
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<a data-sort="3">link</a>
<section data-sort="4">section</section>
<div data-sort="2">block</div>
<a>just a link, without data-sort</a>
<span data-sort="1">line</span>
```

Comment: Ну это, по идее, то же самое, что предлагал я (почти, вы копируете в новый массив сами элементы (это то, до чего я не догадался), а я копировал значения атрибутов). Вот очень интересно решение с `[].sort.call(...)`.

Comment: Я именно этого чего-то и ожидал. Только я думал, что надо будет использовать прототипы, а тут лямбды какие-то (к сожалению, с ними еще плохо знаком).

Comment: @smellyshovel обновил ответ насчет call()

Comment: Вот! Если бы вы еще объяснили суть этого кода `[].slice.call(collection);`, то цены бы не было ответу. Как можно "нарезать" пустой массив? И что делает `call` с ним потом?

Comment: @smellyshovel полее подробно в разделе "одалживание метода" https://learn.javascript.ru/call-apply#%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

Comment: Благодарю. Теперь это точно решение. Спасибо вам.